# Proving the existence of a harmonic function

Tags: calculus

Show that if $f(u,v)$ is harmonic, then $F(x,y)=f(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is also harmonic.

What i did

For a harmonic function to exist, $F_{xx}$ +$F_{yy}$= 0 Hence i know that i must show this result. I then let $u=x^2+y^2$ and $v=2xy$

so $f(x,y)=f(u(x,y),v(x,y))$

from here i know that i must take the chain rule of this function but im unsure of how to peform the chain rule of this function and continue from here. Could anyone help me in this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look up multidimensional chain rule.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f \circ g(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} g_k(x) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} f(y)|_{y=g(x)}$$
Where $g = (g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_n)^T$. In your case $g_1 = u, g_2 = v$ and $f$ is the harmonic function. ($n=2$)